# Loading website from a different domain PHP

Tags: php

In my application I am loading product info from a supplier:

```
$start_url = "http://www.example.com/product/product_code";
```

These URLs are usually redirected by the supplier's website, and I have written a function that successfully finds the destination URL, like so:

```
$end_url = destination( $start_url );
echo "<a href=\"$start_url\">start url</a>"; // link get redirected to correct page
echo "<a href=\"$end_url\">end url</a>"; // links straight to correct page, no redirection
```

However, if I want to get the HTML from the page...

```
echo file_get_contents( $start_url );  // 404
echo file_get_contents( $end_url );  // 404
```

...I just get the supplier's 404 page (not a generic one but their custom one).

I have `allow_url_fopen` enabled; `file_get_contents( "http://www.example.com/" )` works fine.

I can use either URL to load the expected content in an `iframe` client-side, but XSS security prevents me extracting the data I need.

The only thing I can think of is if the site is using an URL rewriter, could this mess things up?

The PHP is running on my local machine, so it should appear no different from me looking at the website via a browser as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Ok, so what does `destination()` do? Your problem is most likely there. Or the site is throwing a 404 for bots with `php` as the useragent.

Comment: Essentially it tests the response for a `Location:` redirect, and then tests the new url, until it no longer receives a redirect and returns the final url.  This seems to work as the urls it produces work in the address bar/iframe src when requested with ajax.

I hadn't thought of the user agent - I'll investigate.

Comment: You might want to look into using curl, your be able to set the useragent, session or cookies plus follow the redirects  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION (as long as no base dir restriction in effect ect) with a few lines of code, plus curl is like 50% faster then std fgc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Loz Cherone ツ's comments, using cURL and [changing the user agent](http://davidwalsh.name/set-user-agent-php-curl-spoof) worked.

```
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13";

$url = $_REQUEST["url"];  // e.g. www.example.com/product/ABC123            

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  // follows any redirection
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

echo curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

I then put the response into the  `srcdoc` attribute of an `iframe` client-side so I can access the DOM.